# Terraform: count == true

Tags: terraform

I have used this previously in my TF code:

```
count   = "${var.whatever == "true" ? 1 : 0}"
```

Which works great for what I wanted to use. However, I'm thinking of how best to use something similar to say, if `var.whatever` is equal to `true`, then count is equal to `length(var.whatever)`.

Would this work?

`count = "${var.whatever == "true" ? ${length(var.whatever) : 0}"`

It's just that I was always under the impression with TF that you can't nest interpolations.

Also, this kind of leads me to another interesting question.. what do you guys use to test syntax? I don't mean to lint the TF Code, I mean something to run the code against to test things like this? I don't want to just deploy to dev, just to test the output of my TF code. I was wondering if there was something, shell like, which I could literally test this stuff as is it were `bash` or something. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hello @jonnybinthemix - since the last paragraph is essentially a different question, it's best to remove it from this Q and place it into its own. Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your original idea won't work because if `var.whatever` is a list, then it can't also be a string (i.e. *= "true"*).

However, the good news is that interpolations can be used inside the general ternary operator.

So you can have something like:

```
count = "${var.bool == "true" ? length(var.whatever) : 0}"
```

---

A good way to test out interpolations before dropping them into your final code is by using [Terraform's *console* feature](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/console.html) (i.e. `terraform console`).

Set up your vars in a file, say `console.tf` in a directory without any other TF code.

```
variable "whatever" {
  type = "list"
  default = ["1", "2", "foo", "bar" ]
}

variable "bool" {
  default = "true"
}
```

Now from the command line, run `terraform console`.

```
$ terraform console
>  var.whatever
[
  "1",
  "2",
  "foo",
  "bar",
]
> length(var.whatever)
4
> "${var.bool == "true" ? length(var.whatever) : 0}"
4
> exit
$
```

You can see that Terraform performs the interpolations, then runs the ternary operator on those evaluated values.